# Need Help in ResumeParsing Web Service

Tags: php, web-services, resume

I am using a webservice for resume parsing but he webservice returns error. Kindly view my code and let me know asap. I am trying it from last 1 day but failed all time.

```
$client = new SoapClient("http://services.resumeparsing.com/ResumeService.asmx?wsdl");
$data = 'POST /ResumeService.asmx HTTP/1.1
Host: services.resumeparsing.com
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8

SOAPAction: "http://services.resumeparsing.com/ParseResume"
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap12:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap12="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
<soap12:Body>
 <ParseResume xmlns="http://services.resumeparsing.com/">
 <request>
<AccountId>36463356</AccountId>                     <ServiceKey>70ZgH1VZztLWIqNMByDnkjMImOkHS060kPjIObwP</ServiceKey>
<FileBytes>'.$contents.'</FileBytes>
</request>

</ParseResume>
</soap12:Body>
</soap:Envelope>';
$result = $client->ParseResume($data);
print_r($result);
```

But the response is

> stdClass Object ( [Code] => MissingRequestParameter [Message] => Missing Request Parameter: The required parameter named 'request' is missing. [UsesRemaining] => 0 )

I cant understand that what is missed in this request, i have done this in .net and its working fine but in php it does not work....

Comment: did you connected to their support team to check. I remember we faced similar solution in our implementation and rchilli team did end to end support and solved it without much pain.